# Is such a question going to be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have a service, for which I have to develop such a mechanism which issues notification to the administrator if it fails.

I already have few ideas in my head about how this might or might not work, but I would like to ask the experts here if there are other possible solutions.

Would such a question be on-topic on this .SE ?

Comment: I think most administrators won't rely (exclusively) on the ability of any application or service to monitor itself but would cheer for any application that provides a useful interface that easily ties it in with their existing monitoring solution and the community can probably give you some useful pointers there.

Comment: `snmp` and `syslog` are examples of useful interfaces.

Answer (score 8):

Without seeing your actual question it's difficult to tell. The best thing to do is just ask and see how the community responds to it. It may though, fall foul of

> Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

It may also be a duplicate of

- [What am I looking for in a Monitoring Solution?](https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution)

or it's related

- [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

Answer (score 4):

So you want to develop a... monitoring and/or alerting service?  O...K.  I'd recommend buying my book titled:  *The Wheel, and How to Reinvent It*.

Like Iain said, it's hard to say for sure without seeing your actual question, but if your question really does boil down to how to reinvent a monitoring/alerting system, or which one of the 8 trillion you should use, it will probably not be received well.

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to develop a new Nagios, but is instead asking for pointers on how to make the failure of his service visible to monitoring tools.

Comment: @Reaces I hope that's the case, but the wording makes me suspect it's not. `I have a service, for which I have to develop [...] a mechanism which issues notification to the administrator if it fails.` Typically, the notification mechanism would be a monitoring service sending out an email/SMS to an administrator, and the mechanism for detecting failure would be... using your monitoring system to monitor the service in question. I really don't see how either requires development effort, unless, of course, he's trying develop a monitoring system specifically for/into this service he mentions.

Comment: he could be using the service monitoring/recovery stuff in windows but it's hard to tell without the actual details- and why what's there isn't sufficient